# Reading a double/float value on GUI text field

Tags: java, user-interface, parsing, netbeans, double

I'm trying to build a GUI on NetBeans that calculates the mean of a set of values. Currently it works with whole number values, but when I try to input decimal values into the text field it only reads the part before the decimal point before moving on to the next value in the array (e.g. if I input `1.4, 2.5, 3.6` it reads it as `1, 2, 3` and calculates the mean as `2` instead of `2.5`)

How do I get the computer to register the entire value?

```
    private void getMeanButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                               

    String[] stringValues = valuesTextField.getText().split(",");
    double[] values = new double[stringValues.length];


  for(int i = 0; i < stringValues.length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[i]);
    }

    int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
{
        sum += values[i];
}

    double mean = 0;
    mean = (double)sum / (double)values.length;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mean);
}
```

By the way, I've checked the stringValues array and all is good there-- the entire value is registered. Something seems to be going wrong in the parsing.

Comment: "It reads it as 1, 2, 3": no it doesn't, and you haven't provided any evidence to the contrary.

Comment: My bad, new to programming and just guessed that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you have defined your sum as an int and not double

```
...
double sum; 
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
{
    sum += values[i];
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @piyushjaiswal This is an answer, not a comment.